# Why does my async.waterfall javascript sequential code not end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

When I run the following code, that sequentially connects to MongoDB, then closes, using async.waterfall in javascript, the program does not end as expected.  Instead it appears to just wait after the 'DB closed" line.

```
$ node test-async2.js
hit connectMongo
Connected correctly to server, DB: notes
hit closeMongo
DB closed

[program just waits here, doesn't end]
```

I was expecting the program to end.  What mistake am I making?

```
const
  async = require('async'),
  MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/notes';    

function connectMongo(next) {
  console.log('hit connectMongo');
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    console.log("Connected to server, DB: " + db.databaseName);
    next(null, db);
  });
}

function closeMongo(db, next) {
  console.log('hit closeMongo');
  db.close;
  next(null, "DB closed");
}

// perform connect then close sequentially
async.waterfall([
  connectMongo,
  closeMongo,
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the program to end.`  ? What ever written in the code, that is what is happening. I think` ctrl+c` will help you stopping your program. I don't think it will automatically end.

Comment: Are you calling `close`? There are no parentheses.

Comment: @cartant - that's it, thanks so much.  I had been staring at the code so long I just couldn't see a stupid mistake.  Thanks again !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try db.close() instead of db.close

Also, add a callback to db.close to check for errors while closing.

Comment: many thanks @Tom, I couldn't see the stupid mistake that was right in front of me.  Good point also about checking for errors on close - thanks again.